# How does JavaScript function know the variable of my argument is a number and not a string?

Tags: javascript

Notice I don't declare any variable. I don't say anything like `let num = ""`.

```
function add2(num) 
{
   return num += 2;
}

console.log(add2(5));
```

Comment: JS doesn't really "know" anything. Try `add2("hello")` and it would also "work", as in - not throw an error.

Comment: "*Notice I don't declare any variable.*" you *did* - notice your function declaration: `function add2(num)`

Comment: Use TypeScript if you want type safety, otherwise `num` can be any type when the code executes. What you mean by "know" is unclear. Are you referring to types at runtime, or...? If so, the types belong to the data the variable refers to and is just passed along to the parameter dynamically. So if you call `add2` with a string, `num` will be a string, if you call it with an array, `num` will be an array.

Comment: While JavaScript does have specific native types (i.e.. string, boolean, number, symbol), it **implicitly** assigns data into those types based on how they are used in your statements. Also, by listing `num` as part of your function declaration, you are in fact declaring a local variable called `num`.

Comment: `let num = ""` does not magically mean you store a string. You can dump in an object, number, an array, or whatever else into that. There is nothing magical with `let num = ""` in JavaScript. `let num = ''; num={}; num=3; num=[]; num = () => {};`

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. Whatever argument is passed into the parameter is what JS works with, regardless of the data type. So it doesn't "know" whether the parameter is a string or a number prior to the argument being passed in.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an *interpreted* language, so it will interpret the types at runtime. If you pass an integer into the `add2` function, it will add 2 to the integer. But if you pass in a string into the `add2` function, the interpreter will attempt to add 2 to the string.

If you want to explicitly declare types, you can use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).